# What is 'normal' phantom drain for a US household?

Tags: wiring

I live in a 3,500 sq. ft. house in Minneapolis, MN, my power bills have been extremely high, and I'm trying to track down any sources of phantom drain as I think the draw is inappropriate.

With most everything  than can be powered down, both HVAC systems off, well pump not running, computers shut down, all lights and ceiling fans in the house off (except for the utility room lights), I'm having about a 1,000W constant draw. With a current clamp, I'm reading 2.06A on one phase and 6.36A on the other.

From what I've traced down so far out of the 1kW draw:

- 50W: Cable Modem, 2x Routers, a few monitors on Standby
- 40W: Outdoor bug trap
- 10W: Security Panel
- 100W: Utility room lights while I was measuring at the panel (motion activated)

This leaves about 800W with no obvious source of where it is going. I will be tracing down each circuit next, the highest current branches being 2x ~1.5A, 2x ~1A, 3 ~0.5A, and 2x ~0.3A.

Is this anywhere in the realm of a normal phantom draw for a house of that size?

Since I'm operating under the assumption that it is not normal, what would be good items to check if I have unplugged everything that can be unplugged and the draw still remains?

Other than TVs in standby and my two refrigerators, what would be good candidates to plug into my kill-a-watt and measure their draws?

### Edit

I have measured the standby/resting stable current of everything I have plugged in to an outlet, and came to 340W.

The only remaining things plugged in are permanently wired:

- Three light fixtures that turn on when I'm in the utility room measuring current
- light fixtures while off
- dishwasher while off
- furnace/AC 1 while not running
- furnace/AC 2 while not running

These probably have some draw while off, but let's be more than generous until I measure them and say 500W total.

This means I have a solid 500W going somewhere, in my house, completely unaccounted for. Nothing I can think of can plausibly be dissipating this much power without a trace.

Comment: Sounds massive to me! At UK energy prices that's something like £1000 a year :o

Comment: If you can see the drain on the meter - try turning off each circuit breaker one-by-one until it stops. That narrows it down to one circuit. 1000W is high for *nothing* - that's, like, a small vacuum cleaner going *all the time*.

Comment: sounds like a really old fridge and an old freezer, both defectively running at full power continuously, could do that. But two half-way normal fridges? Unlikely, then again, don't know US-American fridges.

Comment: I'd be opening all the breakers until you find the culprit(s). It's most likely something you've forgotten though.

Comment: beside of fridges, water heater/boiler, fresh water / warm water pumps, heating pumps, Outdoor ligths, extra freezer cabinet, also all kinds of machines: washing, coffee, ... have standby currents nowadays. Plus: there might be damaged stuff!

Comment: Did you multiply AC voltage by AC current to calculate that 1kW power draw ?

Comment: How well do you know your house? Could it have a fresh air heat exchange system that is powered? Could there be a heater for prevention of freezing pipes that is hidden away someplace? Could there be an attic or crawl-space light that is on all the time? Intercom system? Antenna amplifier?  Motion sensing lights? There could be a lot of standby power, but it seems more likely that there one or more substantial loads that are hidden away somehow.

Comment: @IshanFdo1 I have a current monitor (clamps around main phases) that is reporting ~1000W, and when I clamp the phases, add the amperage, and multiply by 120, I get a similar result: (2.36A+6.06A)*120V = 1010W.

Comment: @CharlesCowie I moved in three years ago, and I'm familiar with most of what I can see. For sure it's not a single thing doing the 1000W, as there are significant draws on 9 different branches with almost everything I can get to turned off. There are a number of intermittent loads, but none that I would expect to be constant: 2x sump pumps, septic transfer pump, well pump, 2x furnaces, main fridge, mini fridge, sprinkler system. That measured load was with all lights off other than the utility room, including outdoor lights and almost all intermittent loads (except fridges) turned off.

Comment: @schnedan Yeah I get the standby current, but 6.6A/800W of standby current seems over the top. My water heater and dryer use natural gas.

Comment: Newer water heaters have electrically driven draft fans, and I expect dryers do also. However the fans would only go on when the appliance runs, so you would not be likely to overlook them. Mutliplying AC voltage by current gives apparent power. The real power is somewhat less, in some cases a lot less. However the 1000 VA that you are measuring seems like a lot and may represent quite a bit of real power. Your Kill-A-Watt will tell you the VA and pf as well as the watts. You should probably measure the standby watts and VA of as many items as you can.

Comment: "computers shut down" Current PCs have standby supplies that stay on when shutdown. You'll need to unplug any PCs or switch them off with a mechanical switch on the back panel. (That won't take 800 VA, of course.)

Comment: @GrahamNye Most of my computers, monitors, cable modem and one router are at my desk. With 3x laptops shutdown and 1x desktop shut down, 5x monitors in standby, the cable modem and router, I was getting 40W shown on the display of the UPS they are plugged into - not sure if it's real power or apparent power. I allowed for 10W from the other router in my 50W figure above. There are five more laptops, powered down, fully charged around the house, as well as a few phones, but I'd be astonished if those amounted to 800VA.

Comment: As Far as phantom drain I have never found it to be real or enough to measure.what I have found... All the chargers that are plugged in even if not powering devices create a fair load you may have the laptop turned off but feel the charger / wall wart or brick most of the time these will be warm because they use electricity that warmth is watts being consumed not phantom. I used to have a commercial coffee maker I found that that thing drew an amp almost all the time keeping the water hot, sound bars , TV sets cable or satellite boxes all add up and fairly quickly.

Comment: @EdBeal See my edit. I used a Kill-A-Watt to measure everything plugged into my outlets, and got 340W.

Comment: @Ehryk -- can you get instantaneous power out of your watt-hour meter? (you can use stopwatch trickery to do it on old-school mechanical meters, smart meters may toss it on the LCD as one of a set of alternating measurements)

Comment: Ehryk was the kill-a-watt meter calibrated to prior to the measurements? what loadcell were you using? What clamp was it calibrated? There is variance of .3-5% with the smaller slugs and the larger ones are worse for for pro models. power apparent and power true next what clamp? To get accurate power measurements it truly takes meter that cost about 10x any of the kill a watt meters except the ones that have multiple slugs but those start much higher. As an electrician That has worked in many fields I can tell you many meters are considered as absolute junk until the 1k$ what model do you have

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I can just set it to watts / instantaneous power, it is a Kill A Watt Edge P4490 https://www.amazon.com/P3-P4490-Kill-Energy-Monitor/dp/B00CCJA2ZK

Comment: @EdBeal No, it was not calibrated prior to measuring. I don't know what a loadcell is. It's not a current clamp type; it goes in-line with load and reports load on its LCD with an internal shunt resistor and volt meter. In the spec sheet, it reports a 'Typical' accuracy of 1%, with a 'Maximum' of 2%. Model is in the previous comment; I appreciate that these aren't very precise numbers, but 'missing 500W' from a 2% accuracy is beyond the realm of plausibility. Here's the manual with the accuracy figures: http://www.p3international.com/manuals/p4490_manual.pdf

Comment: @SteveSether That's a great suggestion, I checked when I was putting in additional insulation. I have an exhaust fan in the garage that I have not wired in yet, and no other attic fans.

Comment: @Ehryk -- no, I'm talking about the kWh meter your power company installed for the whole house :)

Comment: After looking through the spec sheet the accuracy is stated at 2%+-5w for the power measurements,  sorry but this is double speak for B.S.  if you are measuring 50w and the display is 2% that is 1 watt but add the +-5 watts and it can be 6w off on a 50w measurement. To tell the truth this meter is less accurate than any I have looked at previously.  Now take the clamp if it is similar quality your measurements can be off by 20% . We don’t get accurate measurements with this kind of meter and using 2 different non calibrated standards increases the error possibilities.

Comment: @EdBeal I understand what you are getting at; for the 'total' draw I'm using two different methods. One is a Legion Solar device that has split current transformers clamped around the main input, and the second was me taking a EM306B digital clamp meter to each circuit to get amperage, and they both agreed to an astounding level (8.42A sum of the branches, 1,010W reported on the home device). Again, I appreciate these are not very precise, but I still don't think their lack of precision could amount to missing 500W out of the (1,010W - 340W - some LED lights) from the Kill-a-Watt Edge.

Comment: @EdBeal The 2% +/- 5W is also listed as 'Max' or worst possible case - probably on higher currents. The 'Typ' is 1% without a +/-, and I was measuring very low currents, and for most it would settle on a 0.1W figure that seemed rather precise. On a couple devices that I knew the wattage (like a 5V/1A USB adapter plugged in to a diffuser that draws as much current as it is provided, non-standard USB), it registered 5.1W - seemingly spot on for a 5W output with some conversion inefficiency.

Comment: No it is listed both in the low wattage range and the high wattage range. You can keep pulling your hair out but cheap test equipment is just that cheap. Look at the specs on the clamp meter similar plus as I mentioned positioning a clamp makes a difference. Anything plugged in even if charged and turned off still draws power door bell transformers furnace transformers yes even if not ringing or actively running feel the transformers they are warm that is wattage being consumed. I won’t even start on what my meters cost but you are asking a grand total of 80.00 test equipment to do  a 1000 job

Comment: @Ehryk -- have you tried looking at the kWh meter that your utility put on your house to measure your power consumption and send you your monthly bill...?  It's something that's *going* to be reasonably calibrated (given that it's the power company's meter after all, and they'd get hammered by the PUC for sending out bogus bills), and I haven't heard of any reasonably modern kWh meter that can't do instantaneous power (either by timing the spinning disc on an electromechanical meter, or displaying it directly on a smart meter)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I have, it is a smart meter that bounces through a number of readings. Next time I shut everything down, I will unplug the refrigerators, track down which breakers the furnaces are on, shut those down, and cross reference the meter's reading with my montitoring device and clamp meter. O'm fairly certain I've been getting billed for it, our rate is 11 cents/kWh and I've been paying about $200/month in power, with higher usage than I can account for.

Comment: @Ehryk -- have you tried turning off the main and using your smartmeter to verify the power consumption with no breakers on, then turning on the main and turning off all the branches and checking power consumption *then*, then turning each branch circuit on one at a time and recording all the results?  That'd get you a top-down view of the situation...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Yeah I can try that, but out of curiosity, how would that be different from monitoring the total draw (which hovered around 1010W while I was measuring) and putting my clamp on each branch, and measuring the current? I have identified 9 branches with >0.2A, which add to 7.1A, or ~852W. What does turning the circuit off do for me? I'd have to wait a while for some circuits to settle if I did that, plugging in a TV takes ~1 minute for it to boot and enter standby, after which it drops to ~1W.

Comment: @Ehryk -- I'm trying to rule out sources of parasite draw in the breaker panel (GFCI and/or AFCI breakers need power for their own internal electronics), as well as any hinkiness in the wiring

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Ah, got it. I have no GCFI or AFCI breakers in the panel, but I do have GFCI outlets on every circuit with outlets. I just expect them to register with the clamp meter right after the breaker. The refridgerators and furnaces while off seem to be prime candidates for phantom drain.

Comment: @Ehryk -- still want to rule out any weird taps or whatnot though

Comment: GCFI is going to draw a very tiny amount of power, maybe a watt.   500 watts is a LOT of power.  In terms of just pure heat, it's a small space heater.

Comment: @SteveSether someone with lab test equipment has the Leviton GFCI outlets I have at 3W constant draw; I have between 10-20 in the house, so they account for 30-60W.

Comment: @Ehryk Maybe it's 3 watts.  You should be able to fairly easily test the current draw of a GFCI with a good multi-meter.  You of course have to be careful, since it'd require taking out the GFCI, and connecting a muti-meter (with probes connected right) to a live circuit.  I can't think of any reason why it wouldn't work though....

Comment: @SteveSether I'm adept with working with electricity, and was the one who put them all in, and I'm prepping to replace my main panel. However, I simply don't have anything that I'd trust to be accurate to that level, which is why I'm going with someone else's result for the 3W figure - I don't trust any of my multimeters enough :)

Comment: @Ehryk I have a very trustworthy multi-meter.  I'm at least a little curious if my GFCI outlets draw as much as 3 watts, so I'll do some testing myself and report back.  3 watts is about $3 a year, so it's possible that replacing a high power usage GFCI with a lower one may be worth it.

Answer (score 2):

Older Fridges can draw upwards of 300 W  (while in defrost for example), and can average over 150W even if they are working correctly.  If you've got two of them, that could be your load and could explain the variance (if one were in defrost while measuring).  1KVA "Phantom" load for a 3500 sqft house doesn't seem *totally* unreasonable.  You've already found 500-700w of draw.  Everyone's circuit breaker idea (in comments above) is good to localize which circuit the phantom drain is attached to.

Comment: I measured both refrigerators when running. My main fridge in the kitchen draws 7W while running, the mini-fridge draws 60W while running. Next time I shut everything down, I'll unplug the refrigerators just to take them out of the equasion, but assuming they are both running that's only 67W.

Comment: Read the answer and understand the compressor is not running on most units while in defrost mode.

Comment: @EdBeal got it. I will unplug both refrigerators next time I shut everything down, as well as turning off the breakers for the two furnaces, to remove all of them as variables.

Comment: You need to verify the wattage also your main fridge 7w I don’t know any electric fridge that consumes only 7w that’s barely enough to keep electronic controls running and when the compressor starts the drain will be closer to 1000w for a short time.